# Facebook app_scoped_user_id throwing 404

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have profile link for all users saved in my db that I use to navigate to user profile. example- `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1568636049896083/`

Since yesterday all such urls have started throwing 404. I tried to google it but could not find reason. Does anyone know what has happened ?

Comment: Facing similar problem.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/

Comment: Same here. is this a "change" or a "bug"? I couldn't see anything about this in release notes